# Trouble with batch file using echo to print text to file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that creates another batch file. I am trying to get the batch file to print the following line to a new batch file:

```vb
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%CD%\file.exe">>script.vbs
```

This is the line of code I am using:

```vb
echo     echo oLink.TargetPath = "%CD%\file.exe"^>^>script.vbs>>"newfile.bat"
```

Of course what this prints to the new file is:

```vb
echo oLink.TargetPath = "(Directory I Run The Batch File From)\file.exe">>script.vbs
```

I need the file to print the variable `%CD%` to the new file instead of the variable output of the current directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The % character has a special meaning for command line parameters and FOR parameters.

To treat a percent as a regular character, double it:

```
%%
```

Which gives :

```
echo oLink.TargetPath = '%%CD%%\file.exe' >f
```

Reference:
[How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html).

Comment: When I do that it prints this - echo oLink.TargetPath = "^\file.exe">>script.vbs

Comment: You need to escape every special character : `echo oLink.TargetPath = ^"^%CD^%\file.exe^"`

Comment: Doing that printed this to the file - echo oLink.TargetPath = "\file.exe">>script.vbs

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: I tried a batch file with only this line in it: ```echo     echo oLink.TargetPath = ^"^%CD^%\file.exe^"^>^>script.vbs>>"testing.bat"``` and I get the same result to the printed file - echo oLink.TargetPath = "\file.exe">>script.vbs

Comment: Your solution works in the command prompt printing to the screen, But it does not work when running through a batch file.

Comment: The problem is the percent character. Fixed.

Comment: Basically, the percent character in unquotable in a batch file and causes real funny effects.

Answer (score 1):

The correct escape character for a percent symbol is itself.
`Echo(%%CD%%`